# Glassfish/JMS: Does each Destinatation Resource require its own Connection Factory?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I'm learning about JMS/Glassfish.  I plan on having multiple message queues (JMS destination resource) set up in the same Glassfish instance.  Do I require a separate JMS connection factory for each queue?  All the examples I found only use one queue, so it's not clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can create multiple destinations with one factory.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely can reuse a connection factory for multiple destinations. Its interesting how  unclear some of the jms basics are. I remember googling for quite a while and I had to try it out myself to verify this.